# Replacing a string from an built-in unknown character in python

Tags: python, unicode, decode

I'm trying to replace this unrecognized � text below here to a another text. What I did is decode it to UTF-8 and try to replace the unknown text below.

" you�"

```py
varlistlabela = spss.GetVariableLabel(var)
varlistlabela=varlistlabela.decode("cp1252").replace(r'[\u0020-\ud7ff]',"").encode("cp1252")
```

Comment: Regular `str.replace` doesn't understand character ranges like `[\u0020-\ud7ff]`. Were you thinking of `re.sub`?

Answer (score 1):

You need a regex substitution:

```
re.sub(r'[^\u0020-\ud7ff]', '', s)
```

where `s` is the input string.

**Code**:

```
import re

s = " you�"
print(re.sub(r'[^\u0020-\ud7ff]', '', s))
#  you
```

Comment: Just curious, is there a range of code points that represents the "unknown" characters?  I see that `chr(65533)` and `chr(65534)` are two different things, while `chr(65535)` seems to be a repeat of the latter